# Jenkins pipeline - change class name of loaded scripts

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline project which `load`s several Groovy scripts. When I run this pipeline, Jenkins names these scripts' classes `Script1`, `Script2`, and so on. These names are displayed when replaying a build. They also appear on exception stack traces. I find this confusing, especially when there is more than a couple of scripts.

Is there any way of setting these names from the pipeline or -preferably- from  within the scripts themselves? So far I tried manipulating the scripts' `metaClass`:

```groovy
this.metaClass.name = 'Foo'                //fails, doesn't find metaClass property
this.class.metaClass.name = 'Foo'          //doesn't fail but has no apparent effect
this.class.metaClass.simpleName = 'Foo'    //idem
this.class.metaClass.canonicalName = 'Foo' //idem
```

**NOTE**: I am well aware of Jenkins shared libraries. This question is meant to focus on `load`ed scripts alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to change the generated class name for a `load`ed script.

- The name generation comes from [the `load` step implementation class `LoadStepExecution`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/b556b7cf10476411ded7fbbf71078d6024cc3fe2/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/steps/LoadStepExecution.java#L40-L60).

  ```java
  String clazz = execution.getNextScriptName(step.getPath());
  ```
- In [`CpsFlowExecution`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/b556b7cf10476411ded7fbbf71078d6024cc3fe2/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsFlowExecution.java#L1472-L1475), the script name is generated from the calling `generateScriptName()` on the `shell` which is a `CpsGroovyShell`. This invocationand removes the `.groovy` suffix.

  ```java
  public String getNextScriptName(String path) {
      return shell.generateScriptName().replaceFirst("[.]groovy$", "");
  }
  ```
- The [`CpsGroovyShell`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/b556b7cf10476411ded7fbbf71078d6024cc3fe2/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsGroovyShell.java#L142-L148) generates the class name, which is where the `Script1.groovy`, `Script2.groovy`, etc. get created from

  ```java
  @Override
  protected synchronized String generateScriptName() {
      if (execution!=null)
          return "Script" + (execution.loadedScripts.size()+1) + ".groovy";
      else
          return super.generateScriptName();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be of some help to some users. By chance I managed to force the name of the script class when explicitly creating a class inside the script, like:

```
class MyOwnScriptClass {
    def someClassMember() {
    }
}

return new MyOwnScriptClass()
```

After `load`ing that file it shows me `MyOwnScriptClass` as class name - for the object which is returned by that script - not the script itself. However for my purposes this is sufficient.